# problem with Shift, Ctrl and Alt button with integrated keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have bought a new notebook: HP Pavilion 15 ab062nl, but have a problem with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> buttons of the keyboard.
For example, when I press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button to type in upper-case letters, some letters appear upper-case, and then it starts writing lower-case letters, though I'm still pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button. It is as if I released the button, but I have not.

I have the same problem with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button (for example, when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>), and the same problem with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> buttons.

Sometimes it works as if these buttons are pressed autonomously. For example, sometimes, when I scroll pages on Firefox (or any other browser) using the scroll wheel of mouse, it is as if I am pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button though I am not, and Firefox resizes the zoom of the page.

Furthermore, I discovered that if I press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> buttons for just a second or two, these problems momentarily disappear; i.e., till the next reboot.

I have noticed this bug with all distributions (ArchLinux, Antergos, Fedora 16, Fedora 23 - GNOME Wayland, Ubuntu 15.10, Ubuntu 14.04, and Debian 8.0.2).
I have tested x86-64 distros, and I have tested with all DEs (even without a DE). I have tried with 32-bit distributions as well but have the same problems.

This is not a hardware problem, because, on Windows, I do not have these problems, and even on a Linux distro on Virtualbox under Windows. And while using an external USB keyboard, I do not face these problems
My hardware:
CPU: AMD A10 8700p
GPU: Radeon R6 + Radeon R7 M360
RAM: 8GB DDR3L 1600MHz

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug for this issue, that appears to be specific to HP, possibly specific to the HP 15.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1532746 and add any information you have.