# Keys malfunctioning - ctrl and shift seem to be pressed when they aren't, or don't work when pressed

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install on a new laptop (less than a month old) and I'm having a hard time with my keyboard.

It seems like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key thinks it's being pressed when it's not. Some examples:

1. On Chrome, when I scroll up or down with the mouse the zoom suddenly changes, the same happens in Sublime Text.
2. When typing <kbd>d</kbd> on a terminal it suddenly closes the current tab.

The above examples happened at random intervals.

Sometimes, when I actually want to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and press it to delete a word on the terminal (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>) it only works the first or second time, then it suddenly stops working (while holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).

It's not just the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key because sometimes happens with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key too.

What I have tried:

- Deleting the `.config`, `.gconf`, `.gnome` and `.gnome2` folders as suggested in a post I found
- Changing the Keyboard Layout
- On my keyboard settings, the "Key presses repeat when key is held down" is checked
- The "Sticky keys" option is off.

My laptop:

- HP Pavilion
- AMD A8-7410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics
- 12 GB RAM
- 1 TB HDD
- Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Extra info:

- I'm using `gnome-session-fallback` as my DE.
- I'm using fglrx driver as an alternative to X.org

### Update

- It's happening with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys too
- It's happening with both the left and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc. keys so I guess we can discard hardware failures as suggested by @whtyger in the comments

Comment: Can it be a physical malfunction of the key on the keyboard (that's my wild guess)? This can be checked by booting your system from LiveCD.

Comment: Thanks @whtyger, I don't have a Live CD right now, but it's happening with both Ctrl keys, do you think both can be physically wrong? what are the chances of that happening?

Comment: H'm, if _both_ of them behave so, than the chances are pretty thin.

Comment: Have you tried the `showkey` command? (may need using from the <ALT-F1> console, not X) This may shed some further light on what's going on?

Comment: @MarkWilliams thank you, I'll try it as soon as I get home and get back to you

Comment: Hi! is your PC a Pavillon 15? There is [another user with a problem similar to yours](http://askubuntu.com/q/697552/29595). We had a [long discussion on the Italian Ask service](http://chiedi.ubuntu-it.org/questions/43532/hp-pavillion-15-ab062nl-problema-tasti-shift-ctrl-e-alt) and it ended up with him contacting a kernel developer, that replied once and then disappeared without further notices.

Comment: @dadexix86 please refer to the [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1532746) I think they have found a temporary solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so after some time of testing and with the help of @Dea1993 and the guys on the [Launchpad bug thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1532746). This is how I fix it.

1. Edit the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` on `/etc/default/grub` to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.dumbkbd=1"
   ```
2. Update grub:

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot

Although this causes the `CAPS LOCK` keyboard led not to blink (but this is, in fact, the expected behavior).

For the record, these are the options I found regarding the i8042 controller:

- `i8042.direct` - Put keyboard port into non-translated mode
- `i8042.dumbkbd` - Pretend that controller can only read data from keyboard and cannot control its state (Don't attempt to blink the leds)
- `i8042.noaux` - Don't check for auxiliary (== mouse) port
- `i8042.nokbd` - Don't check/create keyboard port
- `i8042.noloop` - Disable the AUX Loopback command while probing for the AUX port
- `i8042.nomux` - Don't check presence of an active multiplexing controller
- `i8042.nopnp` - Don't use ACPIPnP / PnPBIOS to discover KBD/AUX controllers
- `i8042.reset` - Reset the controller during init and cleanup
- `i8042.unlock` - Unlock (ignore) the keylock

Answer (score 5):

I've the same problem on HP Pavilion 15 ab062nl.
CPU AMD A10 8700p, GPU radeon r6 + radeon r7 m360, RAM: 8GB DDR3.

Try pressing only Left_SHIFT Key. On my notebook this fixes the problem for a while

[problem with SHIFT, CTRL and ALT button with integrated keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697552/problem-with-shift-ctrl-and-alt-button-with-integrated-keyboard)

I've also opened a [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1532746)

You can add yourself as affected or create a new bug if you think yours is different.

In my opinion it's a problem of compatibility with these HP Keyboards.

Comment: Could you please consider giving me the solution as stated on the launchpad bug? Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

i've finally solved the problem updating BIOS

Comment: Hey Man! Could you share the way you did that? Thanks! I'm still having some issues using the dumb keyboard, sometimes the system hangs.

Comment: i've download from HP site (search your specific model) https://support.hp.com/it-it/drivers
then i'ìve installed the new version of bios under windows 10 (the installer is a .exe)

Answer (score 2):

Does it happen with Unity as the DE?

Do you have a wireless mouse plugged in that is sending phantom signals to take over your computer? I had a similar experience, and it turned out my mouse button was being held down in my bag. Like you said, it was like some strange Sticky Keys situation. When I unplugged the wireless mouse dongle the problem went away.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Unplugging and pluggin in my wireless mouse dongle solved the problem

Comment: This was a lifesaver! Even a restart hadn't helped. It was driving me crazy! Thanks a ton! +50 bounty to you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any remote control software like teamviewer? It may be that the states of the control keys are not handled proper when switching back form a remote controlled session.

Comment: No. I'm not using anything like it