# Keyboard randomly presses or releases modifier keys

Tags: keyboard, firmware

Everytime I install a linux OS on my laptop, I have the same problem with my ctrl, shift and alt keys.

Sometimes it works well, and sometimes pressing shift and a letter give something like:
"SSSsssssssssssssssssssssssssssSssssssssssssssssss"

When I scroll, the ctrl key will sometimes activate from itself and make my browser zoom, etc...
I think it comes from the keyboard firmware, because it shows the same problem even in a terminal with the showkey command.

I am currently on Kubuntu, but I had the same problem on a lot of distributions, but not on windows.

Comment: Clean your keyboard, or replace it. This is a hardware problem.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that I don't have this problem on windows

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742762/keys-malfunctioning-ctrl-and-shift-seem-to-be-pressed-when-they-arent-or-don) 3 years ago, forgot to post it.

This problem arises on some HP laptops.
See the launchpad bug report here:
[Keys malfunctioning - ctrl and shift seem to be pressed when they aren't, or don't work when pressed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742762/keys-malfunctioning-ctrl-and-shift-seem-to-be-pressed-when-they-arent-or-don)

Never found a perfect solution, but the kernel parameter (`i8042.dumbkbd`) acts as a good workaround. If you always use x11 or similar anyway, you won't notice any problem after enabling it, except the caps lock light not switching.