# Shift Key working irregularly i8042

Tags: keyboard, hardware

I am experiencing a very inconsistent behaviour of my notebook's builtin keyboard when trying to type uppercase letters and symbols requiring the Shift key to be pressed.

Specifically some letters (<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd>,<kbd>N</kbd>) and symbols (<kbd>*</kbd>,  <kbd>_</kbd> ) will not appear when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

The letters which are not appearing partly differ between the left and the right <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Most strangely, this behaviour is not consistent. From time to time, some of the letters **do** appear and some don't.

For the symbols <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>_</kbd> not even the caps lock can be used.

Does anyone experience something similar or knows how to solve the issue?

I already checked this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742762/keys-malfunctioning-ctrl-and-shift-seem-to-be-pressed-when-they-arent-or-don), which seemed to sometimes help, but never gave consistent results and I could not safely say that it was because of those changes to the GRUB parameters, that the behaviour improved.

Information about my OS:

`Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`

Information on hardware:

```
System Information
    Manufacturer: MEDION
    Product Name: P15648
    Version: Default string
    Serial Number: 203PE6000831
    UUID: 5ef04b80-5ed6-81ea-31c1-ac675dc0c443
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: ML-230008 30028770
    Family: Akoya
```

Keyboard:

```
AT Raw Set 2 keyboard
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Perhaps this [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215017). Would you be kind to us, next time describe your OS version/flavour and your machine model, thank you. This time the `i8042` was super important to understand what is going on.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka As mentioned I tried to edit the GRUB Default boot parameters. However it only helped very inconsistently, so I could not even say it helped.

Comment: Wow Lenovo Median. Ask the company first.

Comment: The company claims that they only support Windows OS. That is the reason I am asking for help here.